# Groovy - Collection only returns a single value

Tags: groovy

I've got a small code snippet that loops through a node and grabs all its properties.
I can get this to work if I set one variable to grab the properties values (except it has a weird [] surrounding it). But I don't want redundant code so I'm trying to set multiple properties inside the loop, except all that returns is a single value, it's not looping around all the nodes.

**WORKING**

```
String selectNodeLabel = null
selectNodeLabel = JcrUtils.getChildNodes("links").collect{ 
  it.getProperty("label").getString()
}
```

**SINGLE VALUE**

```
String selectNodeLabel = null
String selectNodeMeta = null
String selectNodeFooter= null
String topicNode = null

topicNode = JcrUtils.getChildNodes("links").collect{ 
  selectNodeLabel = it.getProperty("label").getString()
  selectNodeMeta = it.getProperty("meta").getString()
  selectNodeFooter = it.getProperty("footer").getString()
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It is never a bad idea to look at the [Collection API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) and [these useful information](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Collections).

Comment: Can I get an explanation on the down votes please, I'm happy to fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def nodeList = JcrUtils.getChildNodes("links").collect{ 
  [ selectNodeLabel  : it.getProperty("label").getString()
    selectNodeMeta   : it.getProperty("meta").getString()
    selectNodeFooter : it.getProperty("footer").getString() ]
}
```

Then, `nodeList` will be a list of Maps, so you could do:

```
println nodeList*.selectNodeLabel
```

To print all the `selectNodeLabel` values for example.

**To explain** the problems with your code...  Collect creates a list of the elements returned by the closure.  What your *SINGLE VALUE* code is doing is overwriting the values in the `selectNode...` variables, and then setting `topicNode` to the value returned from the closure for each element in `JcrUtils.getChildNodes("links")`.

For this case, `topicNode` will contain a List of `it.getProperty("footer").getString()` (as it is the last line in the Closure